# Interpolation from origin and maximum coordinates

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 3D matrices to compare and I need to adapt the evaluation matrix to the size of the reference matrix. I have information about the position of the origin and maximum voxel as well as the number of voxels in the reference matrix.

> xi, yi, zi = np.meshgrid(np.arange(dose_reference.shape[0]),
> np.arange(dose_reference.shape[1]),
> np.arange(dose_reference.shape[2]),
> indexing='ij')
> points = np.column_stack((xi.flatten(), yi.flatten(), zi.flatten()))
>
> interpolated_func = RegularGridInterpolator((np.arange(dose_evaluation.shape[0]),
> np.arange(dose_evaluation.shape[1]),
> np.arange(dose_evaluation.shape[2])),
> dose_evaluation)
> dose_evaluation = interpolated_func(points).reshape(dose_reference.shape)

it only zooms into my matrix, without adapting the sizes.

Thks

Do you have any other interpolation options for my problem?